# MVC and Razor to display integer when value is empty or 0

Tags: model-view-controller

I have the following code in the View.

```
<span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.comments.comments_id)</span>
<span>@item.comments.comments_id</span>
```

The code below works if comments_id is not 0 or empty.

```
<span>@((item.comments.comments_id == 0) ? 0 : @item.comments.comments_id)</span>
```

If its 0 or empty I get 
`System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

The class contains this

```
public Nullable<int> comments_id { get; set; }
```

How can overcome this issue? thanks in advance.

---- EDit more code ---

```
 public ActionResult Show()
    { 
        var showItems = db.Projects.Include(p => p.Comments).ToList(); // INCLUDES ITEMS FROM BOTH TABLES
        return View(showItems);
    }
```

View

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{ 
<tr>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectName)
    </td>

    <td>   
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments.comments_id) // NOTICE this coming from a different table(Comments tbl).
    </td>

    <td> 
     <span>@((item.Comments.comments_id == 0) ? 0 : @item.Comments.comments_id) // HERE when item.Comments.comments_id has no contents it throws an error. 
        <a href="#">Create</a>                 
    </td>
</tr> 
 }
```

Someone posted something similar but I don't understand the answer. 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1732717.aspx?How+to+check+if+model+property+is+empty+in+View+page

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HasValue to check if a nullable variable has a value or not.

```
<span>@((item.comments.comments_id.HasValue) ? @item.comments.comments_id : 0)</span>
```

**EDIT: Added Example**

Your view code looks like it should work. Below is code I wrote to test your view.  The lambda expression in your controller action won't be executed until it's used.  So it's possible it's not executed until the view is rendered.  This could cause a problem because the database connection may be closed by then.  However, the call to ToList() should execute the lambda expression.  So the problem is probably that item.Comments is null.  You should test to see if it is as I did in my example.

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public class Project
    {
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public ProjectComments Comments { get; set; }
    }
    public class ProjectComments
    {
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> comments_id { get; set; }
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var showItems = new List<Project>();
        showItems.Add(new Project()
        {
            ProjectName = "Project 1",
            Comments = new ProjectComments() { Comments = "some comments", comments_id = 1 }
        });
        showItems.Add(new Project()
        {
            ProjectName = "Project 2",
            Comments = new ProjectComments() { Comments = "more comments", comments_id = null }
        });

        return View(showItems);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model IList<MvcApplication2.Controllers.HomeController.Project>

<table border="1">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments.comments_id)
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>
                @((item.Comments != null && item.Comments.comments_id.HasValue) ? @item.Comments.comments_id : 0)
                <a href="#">Create</a>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: Tried it and am getting the same error. 
`System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: Then item or item.comments is null (assuming this is the line throwing the exception).  You would have to post more code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: I added some example code above to help you locate the problem.

Comment: Scott. Thank you for taking the time to write the testing code. You are correct the item.Comment is null.  I am wondering if I can manipulate the code on the Controller and **set a flag for null items**.